Looking for animated movie seen in early 90s about a young native american teen's quest involving giant animals
I saw an animated movie in early 90s and cannot recall much more. What I'm almost sure it wasn't a Japanese animated film nor a Disney one.
The plot is about some unbalancing issue that disturbed the world, and a young native american teen must go in a quest to learn things and maybe recover some items from ancestral and giant animals.
I think there was a big massive fish in a lake with snow in the landscape.
Maybe there was also a giant eagle and probably a giant mammal, like a bear or the like.
In some case he has to fight against some of this big animals, and in other cases they become allies that provide help and advise.
Cannot remember much more. I have searched in google, wikipedia, IMDB and some long listed commentary discussions.

I'm looking for the exact same movie! Doesn't he fall down a waterfall in his canoe at one point, and have to fight off giant beavers? I think at one point there's either a giant snake or giant eagle as well. I can't find it anywhere, though. I think it would play during Thanksgiving.

@Raena Where are you from? What country did you watch it? Same question to OP. Maybe that will ease the search.

Are you sure it wasn't japanese? It sure looks a lot like Princess Mononoke, 1997.

On a journey to find the cure for a Tatarigami's curse, Ashitaka finds
  himself in the middle of a war between the forest gods and Tatara, a
  mining colony. In this quest he also meets San, the Mononoke Hime.

As you may see, the girl is Native American and has a giant wolf by her side. Also, if you search for "Princess Mononoke Animals" in google, you will find many other giant ones.


The person on the wolf is a girl in Princess Mononoke.

@user1952500 Oh, nice to know. Anyways, he didn't specify if it was a girl or a boy. I just assumed. Haha...

Thanks for your time! But not, I'm really sure I had 6-8 years by that moment (I was born in 1985). I remember a lot when I saw Princess Mononoke for first time. The main character was a native american boy, I'm pretty sure. And he had to deal alone with some huge beasts of anormal size that lived alone in far away places. And it wsan't japanese anime.

@Guif Well. Ok. I hope you find it, because I got curious as well, although my digging brought up no more results.

Maybe this - BraveStarr
A Native American marshal and his friends keep the peace on the frontier planet of New Texas. 
1987 - 1989
Besides that lots of anthropomorphized animals and giant bird in title card

You should add reasons why do you think it is this.

Hey, thanks but no. It wasn't sci-fi story nor a series.

It's the 1988 version of The Legend of Hiawatha !!!!!


Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

I would have never find this. I glanced through this movie a dozen times. I gotta say, I thought the "giant" animals would be a lot more... giant.

Hmm, it doesn't ring a bell to my memories. But what I remember was a younger boy, and it traveled alone, maybe with a bird. And definitely appeared huge animals with some spriritual significance with them, they were some kind and magical archetype. I don't know, maybe I'm reconstructing my memories tol much, but I don't think it is tmThe Legend of Hiathawa. Anywsy, thank you so much for still remembering about this and sharing a possible solution. Have a great Christmas festivities everyone.
